# All email notifications show ID NUMBER instead of DISPLAYED NAME

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, people-picker, email-notification

I have two people picker columns set up in a list, set to display name (with presence).  I pull this value into an email notification workflow I have set up in this list.  However, the email shows the numerical ID instead of the name.  How can I fix this to where the name shows up only?  (I've also tried to display name without presence, to no avail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What shows up in the email is not related to the settings you have for the columns for how they display in the list.

How it shows up in the email is controlled through settings in the workflow, where you specify to use data from those fields, you can choose which user data to use: display name, email address, login, or user ID:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Display Name, set "**Return field as**" to "**Display Name**" for the two people picker columns in your SharePoint Designer workflow, like the below:
[image]

Have a try and let's know the result.